# Build a feature to get feedback on annotations drawn on pdf using adobe embed

Tags: reactjs, adobe, adobe-embed-api

I have some predefined annotations that I'm drawing on the PDF using the addAnnotationsInPDF function.

Users are not allowed to make their own annotations. Now I want to build a feature to get feedback on annotations drawn. I'm using Adobe embed API and showing PDF in Sized Container mode.

Please help me with what thing I can use to get this feedback.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that Embed itself can do, but can be built with front-end code. In order to help, you will need to narrow down your question quite a bit.